# Node.js fs.writeFile() not creating new files?

Tags: node.js, json, fs

I need to create many .json files for the system i am trying to develop. To do this, i ran a for loop over the file names i needed, then used `fs.writeFileSync('filename.json', [data])`.

However, when trying to open these later, and when I try to find them in the project folder, I cannot find them anywhere.

I have tried writing in a name that was less complex and should have appeared in the same directory as my script, however that was fruitless as well. To my understanding, even if my file name wasn't what I expected it to be, I should get at least *something*, somewhere, however I end up with nothing changed.

My current code looks like this:

```
function addEmptyDeparture(date) {
fs.readFileSync(
        __dirname + '/reservations/templates/wkend_dep_template.json',
      (err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err
        fs.writeFileSync(
            getDepartureFileName(date),
            data
        )
      }
    )
}

function getDepartureFileName(date){
    return __dirname + '/reservations/' +
    date.getFullYear() +
    '/departing/' +
    (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    '.json'
}
```

Where `data` is the JSON object returned from fs.readFileSync() and is immediately written into fs.writeFileSync(). I don't think I need to stringify this, since it's already a JSON object, but I may be wrong.

The only reason I think it's not working at all (as opposed to simply not showing up in my project) is that, in a later part of the code, we have this:

```
    fs.readFileSync(
        getDepartureFileName(date)
      )
      .toString()
```

which is where I get an error for not having a file by that name.

It is also worth noting that `date` is a valid date object, as I was able to test that part in a fiddle.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding in the effects of `fs.writeFile()`, or is this not the best way to write .json files for use on a server?

Comment: Please show the whole relevant context of your code.  For example, do you have full error handling such that you would catch and log any errors?  Questions here about code SHOULD include all relevant code and context.  We can't help you fix your code without seeing the actual code.  We can't guess what your code looks like.  Yes, `fs.writeFileSync()` will create new files when used properly, but apparently you either aren't looking in the correct place for the files or you aren't use the function properly.  Can't tell without seeing your code!

Comment: Your code is using the wrong arguments for `fs.readFileSync()`.  Look that up in the doc.  It returns the data and does not use a callback.  So, your `fs.writeFileSync()` is never getting called.

Comment: you have use wrriteFileSync function which is synchronous and but try to callback which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to create similar case using a demo with writeFileSync() creating different files and adding json data to these ,using a for loop. In my case it works . Each time a new file name is created . Here is my GitHub for the same :-

```
var fs = require('fs'); 

// Use readFileSync() method 

// Store the result (return value) of this 
// method in a variable named readMe 
for(let i=0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
var readMe = JSON.stringify({"data" : i});

fs.writeFileSync('writeMe' + i + '.json', readMe, "utf8");
```

}

// Store the content and read from 
// readMe.txt to a file WriteMe.txt

Let me know if this what you have been trying at your end.

Comment: How is this an answer to the OP's actual problem?  The convention here is that we get the OP to clarify their question so we can see what their actual problem is rather than just posting examples of code that we have no idea if they are even relevant to the actual problem the OP is experiencing.  You are making a wild guess and have no idea if this is relevant or not.

Comment: I have implemented the use case exactly mentioned by the user and its working . As described by him , there should be no error . The user can verify the same from the example or use it as it in one's code since the described scenario has been implemented without any change.

Comment: The question is what is the OP doing wrong in their code.  You have no idea if you've answered that or not because they haven't disclosed their code.  We would generally prefer to coach the OP into including their actual code so we can more directly help them fix their specific problem rather than guessing about what their problem might be or trying to offer a generic tutorial that might or might not address the OP's issue.  We want people to ask better questions so we have good, high quality questions that can then get good, high quality answers.  That's all I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You probably are forgetting to stringify the data:

```
fs.writeFileSync('x.json', JSON.stringify({id: 1}))
```

Comment: Do I need to stringify data if it is a JSON object directly from fs.readFile()? Also sorry for the unclear original question

Comment: It has to be a string, fs.readFile() probably returns a Promise. Set a debugger breakpoint so you can inspect those things and make sure they're what you expect.